# Randomizing sound between buttons where one button cannot produce the same sound as the other button

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a form page in which the user must correctly identify words in french once the sound of the word has been played and then type the correct answer in a text box in English. 
I have saved several sound files as WAV and was hoping to use it in the form and laying it out as if it was a list of sound files.
When the form loads I want each button to have it's own sound file saved but in doing so calling the sound file in a random order also once button1 has been assigned a sound file e.g "How much?" then button2 cannot call the same sound file hence removing "How much?" from the list of sound files.
Here is my code so far

```
Public Class Form1
Dim SoundList As New List(Of String)
Dim RandomNumber As New Random
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim getInfo As System.IO.FileInfo
    getInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("C:\Users\MassiveNoob\Documents\FrenchWords")
    'calling the file which has the sounds of each word
    For Each Str As String In getInfo
        SoundList.Add(Str)
    Next
End Sub
Sub RandomizeSound()
    Randomize()
    Dim RandomSoundIndex As Integer = RandomNumber.Next(0, SoundList.Count)
    'randomizing files in the sound file 
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(RandomSoundIndex)
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RandomizeSound()
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    RandomizeSound()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. There are lots of ways of doing this and your question is actually a bit on the broad side.

There are a couple of small issues with your current code. It's much easier to use My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles which just returns a list of file names instead of all the file info.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("d:\temp", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.wav")
```

So. The above bit of code returns a collection of strings. To add this collection to the

```
getInfo.AddRange(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("d:\temp", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.wav"))
```

Also, I added two parameters to specify that ONLY the directory named is searched, and ONLY file names with .wav extensions are added to the list

Rather than choose a random sound every time you click a button, create a list of predefined unique random numbers like this

```
private Sub CreateRandomIndexesToSoundList(numberOfButtons As Integer)
    UniqueRandomNumber.Clear()
    Dim index As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfButtons
        Do
            index = RandomNumber.Next(0, SoundList.Count - 1)
        Loop While UniqueRandomNumber.Contains(index)
        UniqueRandomNumber.Add(index)
    Next
End Sub
```

And then when you click button one, just choose the first index and for button 2 choose the 2nd index and so on as needed. This way you can scale up the number of buttons easily.

So the complete code looks like this

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim SoundList As New List(Of String)
    Dim RandomNumber As New Random
    Dim UniqueRandomNumber As New List(Of Integer)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'get a list of all .wav files in the search directory and
        'add the path and filename to SoundList
        SoundList.Clear()
        SoundList.AddRange(My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("d:\temp", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.wav"))

        CreateRandomIndexesToSoundList(2)
    End Sub

    'Generates a list of unique random numbers in the range of 0 to the numberOfButtons
    private Sub CreateRandomIndexesToSoundList(numberOfButtons As Integer)
        UniqueRandomNumber.Clear()
        Dim index As Integer
        For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfButtons
            Do
                index = RandomNumber.Next(0, SoundList.Count - 1)
            Loop While UniqueRandomNumber.Contains(index)
            UniqueRandomNumber.Add(index)
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Sub Playsound(index As Integer)
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(SoundList(UniqueRandomNumber(index)))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Playsound(0)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Playsound(1)
    End Sub
End Class
```